# Override keyCode events

Tags: jquery, django, jquery-select2, django-autocomplete-light

I have a `Django` application and I am using [django-autocomplete-light](https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light) for my select lists. However, I need to change the default behaviour of the  key press events that are coming from [select2](https://github.com/select2/select2) the underlying `JavaScript` module that the autocomplete uses. The relevant code from `select2` can be found [here](https://github.com/select2/select2/blob/c155ca5b60c2769da333d3922f4a14f54e9e50e4/src/js/select2/core.js#L319), and this is what I want to change.

Essentially I want to change the `keypress` event to this:

```
this.on('keypress', function (evt) {
    var key = evt.which;

    if (self.isOpen()) {
        if (key === KEYS.ESC) {
            self.close();

            evt.preventDefault();
        } else if (key === KEYS.ENTER) {
            self.trigger('results:select', {});

            evt.preventDefault();
        } else if ((key === KEYS.SPACE && evt.ctrlKey)) {
            self.trigger('results:toggle', {});

            evt.preventDefault();
        } else if (key === KEYS.UP) {
            self.trigger('results:previous', {});

            evt.preventDefault();
        } else if (key === KEYS.DOWN || KEYS.TAB) {
            self.trigger('results:next', {});

            evt.preventDefault();
        }
    } else {
        if (key === KEYS.ENTER || key === KEYS.TAB) {
            self.open();

            evt.preventDefault();
        }
    }
});
```

where `KEYS.pressedbutton` equates to the corresponding js keycode.

My template (with some omissions) looks like this:

```
{% block content %}
    <div>
        <h1 class="text-center">Create New Activity</h1>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col"></div>
            <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-8">
                <form role="form" method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {{ form|crispy }}
                    <hr>
                    <h4>Add Key Characteristics</h4>
                    <div id="formset">
                        {{ activitykeycharacteristics_formset.management_form }}
                        {% for form in activitykeycharacteristics_formset.forms %}
                            <div id="{{ activitykeycharacteristics_formset.prefix }}-forms">
                                <div class="form-inline">
                                    {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="{{ field.id_for_label }}" class="form-control-label m-2 requiredField">
                                                {{ field.label }}
                                                <span class="asteriskField">*</span>
                                            </label>
                                            {{ field|add_class:"form-control" }}
                                            {{ field.errors }}
                                        </div>
                                    {% endfor %}

                                    {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
                                        {{ hidden }}
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="form-controls">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="add-form"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
                            </div>
                            <div id="empty-form" style="display: none;">
                                <div class="form-inline">
                                    {% for field in activitykeycharacteristics_formset.empty_form.visible_fields %}
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="{{ field.id_for_label }}" class="form-control-label m-2 requiredField">
                                                {{ field.label }}
                                                <span class="asteriskField">*</span>
                                            </label>
                                            {{ field|add_class:"form-control" }}
                                            {{ field.errors }}
                                        </div>
                                    {% endfor %}

                                    {% for hidden in activitykeycharacteristics_formset.empty_form.hidden_fields %}
                                        {{ hidden }}
                                    {% endfor %}
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary m-2 del-kc" id="delete-form"><i class="fa fa-trash fa-lg"></i></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <button class="primaryAction btn btn-primary pull-right ml-1" type="submit">{% trans "Submit" %}</button>
                    <a class="btn btn-secondary pull-right" href="{{ request.META.HTTP_REFERER }}" role="button">{% trans "Cancel" %}</a>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="col"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}

{% block javascript %}
    {{ block.super }}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'admin/js/vendor/jquery/jquery.js' %}"></script>

    /////This is where the js file I want to change is included/////      
    {{ activitykeycharacteristics_formset.media }}
{% endblock %}
```

I haven't found out a way that I can do this. As the underlying js and css is included in the media of my formset (provided by the module), I'm not even sure if I can directly access the included js. So is there a way I can do this?

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: This seems like a very odd requirement; for what reason do you need this? I would guess there is a better way to achieve it.

Comment: Well I guess I really want to know if I can override those defaults. It doesn't have to directly change that file. I was just trying to show where the default was coming from. My problem is select2 is included in the media of the formset so I'm not entirely sure how I would go about doing this?